# Magento only allows my model to be called capitalized

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I am working on a Magento (1.9.4.3) module. For some reason (only) my models can be called capitalized. For example, my helpers are called like this; `mycompany_module/helper`. But my models can only be called like this; `MyCompany_Module/model`. I would like them to be both like `mycompany_module/` but I can not figure out how to solve this.

`app/etc/modules/MyCompany_Module.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/MyCompany/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </MyCompany_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <mycompany_module>
                    <files>
                        <default>MyCompany_Module.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </mycompany_module>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mycompany_module module="mycompany_module">
                    <file>mycompany/module.xml</file>
                </mycompany_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <mycompany_module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompany_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </mycompany_module>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mycompany_module>
                <class>MyCompany_Module_Block</class>
            </mycompany_module>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <mycompany_module>
                <class>MyCompany_Module_Helper</class>
            </mycompany_module>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <mycompany_module>
                <class>MyCompany_Module_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mycompany_module_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mycompany_module>
            <mycompany_module_mysql4>
                <class>MyCompany_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <company>
                        <table>mycompany_module_company</table>
                    </company>
                    <review>
                        <table>mycompany_module_review</table>
                    </review>
                </entities>
            </mycompany_module_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <mycompany_module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MyCompany_Module</module>
                    <class>MyCompany_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mycompany_module_setup>
            <mycompany_module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </mycompany_module_write>
            <mycompany_module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </mycompany_module_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mycompany_module>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompany_Module</module>
                    <frontName>admin_mycompany_module</frontName>
                </args>
            </mycompany_module>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <mycompany_module>
                    <files>
                        <default>MyCompany_Module.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </mycompany_module>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <report translate="title" module="report">
                            <title>module</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <mycompany_index translate="title">
                                    <title>module example</title>
                                </mycompany_index>
                            </children>
                        </report>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mycompany_module>
                    <file>mycompany/module.xml</file>
                </mycompany_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: I have solved this issue, it seemed that it only could be called capitalized but there were some underlaying issues. For instance; the models had a `__construct` method, but models crash when you have a doube underscore in front of the construct method. I switched the constructor name to `_construct` which resolved the issue.